# KeyListener does not work for the whole JFrame

Tags: java, swing, input, keylistener

So, I need that my shortcuts work "globally" in my application, but *just* in my application (Nope, not writing a key logger, as every search in google suggests by using the word "globally"). I've previously assigned the key listener to a JTabbedPane, and it does work when in focus, but there are lists and combos and the whole GUI thing, which is a problem. When assigning to a JFrame, it does not work anywhere. I need a "focus-less" keyListener that gets attached to the very existence of the application. How can I "`Swing.addKeyListener()`"?

```
// Keyboard Shortcuts

    this.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

            CheckShortcut controlShortcut = (key) -> {
                return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && evt.isControlDown();
            };
            // I know getModifiers() is deprecated, wrote the code a while ago.
            CheckShortcut shiftShortcut = (key) -> {
                return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0);
            };

            CheckShortcut controlShiftShortcut = (key) -> {
                int down = KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
                return ((evt.getModifiersEx() & down) == down && (evt.getKeyCode() == key));
            };

            // Control shortcuts.

            if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_N)) {
                createNewFile();
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_O)) {
                openFile();
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                save();
                saveCashRegisters();
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_Q)) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
                MainFrame.toggleFrame(qrWebcamFrame);
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_C)) {
                MainFrame.toggleFrame(comandaCreationFrame);
            } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_P)) {
                if (accessPasswordFrame("Senha de administrador", "Login: ", "Senha de administrador inválida.",
                        ADMIN_TYPE)) {
                    MainFrame.toggleFrame(productFrame);
                }
            }

            // Shift shortcuts.

            if (shiftShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                if (accessPasswordFrame("Senha de administrador", "Login: ", "Senha de administrador inválida.",
                        ADMIN_TYPE)) {
                    MainFrame.toggleFrame(passwordFrame);
                }
            }

            // Control shift shortcuts.

            if (controlShiftShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                saveAs();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: `I need that my shortcuts work "globally" in my application` - use "Key Bindings", not a KeyListener. The Swing tutorial has a section on Key Bindings. The forum has plenty of examples. Or the easier way is to create a menubar with menu items and assign accelerators to the menu item. This way you have a self documenting interface since the advanced user can learn the binding and the beginner can use the menu.

Comment: [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), this is exactly the type of job they were designed for. You could also get the same functionality from `JMenu`, `JMenuItem` and `JMenuBar`